# generate fake-valid data with pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like to create automated examples of valid data based on my `pydantic` models. How can I do this?

Example:

```
import pydantic
from typing import Any


class ExampleData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str = pydantic.Field(min_length=10, max_length=10)
    
    @staticmethod
    def example() -> dict[str, Any]:
        # some logic
        return {}
        


a.example()
"""Returns
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": "0123456789"
}
"""
```

P.S. I suspect that `pydantic` provides this functionality because `fastapi` generates sample data, but I'm not sure if this is exactly its functionality and I couldn't find such a method. Can any one help me understand this?

Comment: Have you tried factoryboy? https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ it should work with pydantic model

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it using `pydantic` and `Faker`:

- Installation

```
pip install Faker
pip install pydantic
```

- Script

```
import uuid
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, UUID4
from faker import Faker

# your pydantic model
class Person(BaseModel):
    id: UUID4
    name: str
    hobbies: List[str]
    age: Union[float, int]
    birthday: Union[datetime, date]

class PersonFactory:
    @classmethod
    def generate_id(cls):
        return str(uuid.uuid4())

    @classmethod
    def generate_name(cls):
        # Implement your own logic to generate realistic names
        return Faker().name()

    @classmethod
    def generate_hobbies(cls):
        # Implement your own logic to generate hobbies
        return Faker().words(nb=1)

    @classmethod
    def generate_age(cls):
        # Implement your own logic to generate realistic ages
        return Faker().random_int(1940, 2023)
        
    
    @classmethod
    def generate_birthday(cls):
        # Implement your own logic to generate realistic birthdays
        return Faker().date_of_birth(tzinfo=None, minimum_age=18, maximum_age=80)

    @classmethod
    def build(cls):
        id = cls.generate_id()
        name = cls.generate_name()
        hobbies = cls.generate_hobbies()
        birthday = cls.generate_birthday()
        age = datetime.now().year - birthday.year
        
        return Person(id=id, name=name, hobbies=hobbies, age=age, birthday=birthday)

result = PersonFactory.build()
print(result)
```

- Output:

```
id=UUID('4b7ffc04-48a1-4f4d-8c5b-d3167717dd69')
name='Katherine Brown'
hobbies=['stay']
age=30
birthday=datetime.date(1993, 2, 17)
```

This will generate a fake person data everytime you run `PersonFactory.build()`

Answer (score 2):

A more hands-on approach is to populate the `example` attribute of fields, then create an object with those values.

> **Note:** this doe not guarantee your examples will pass validation.

```py
import pydantic
from typing import Any


class ExampleData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: int = pydantic.Field(example=1)
    b: str = pydantic.Field(min_length=10, max_length=10, example="abc-123-45")
    
    @classmethod
    def example(cls: 'ExampleData') -> dict[str, Any]:
        # some logic
        return populate_with_examples(cls)
        


def populate_with_examples(model: pydantic.BaseModel) -> dict:
    """Populate fields with example values"""

    result = {}

    # pydantic V1 uses __fields__
    for name, field in model.__fields__.items():

        # Populate with example
        result[name] = field.field_info.extra.get("example")

    return dict(result)


# Call it
ExampleData.example()
# {'a': 1, 'b': 'abc-123-45'}
```

### Nested Models:

This approach is especially useful for working with nested models:

> I've also extended to work for `default` value

```py
class Nested(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: str = pydantic.Field(example="hello")


class ExampleData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    a: int = pydantic.Field(example=1)
    b: str = pydantic.Field(min_length=10, max_length=10, example="abc-123-45")
    c: int = pydantic.Field(default=100)
    # Note: Example will be populated by child, so no explicit example needs
    # to be provided for nested models
    n: Nested


def populate_with_examples_recursive(model: pydantic.BaseModel) -> dict:
    """Populate fields with example values"""

    result = {}

    # pydantic V1 uses __fields__
    for name, field in model.__fields__.items():
        if issubclass(field.type_, pydantic.BaseModel):
            result[name] = populate_with_examples_recursive(field.type_)
        else:
            result[name] = field.field_info.extra.get("example")
            # Or default value
            if result[name] is None:
                result[name] = field.default

    return dict(result)


# Execute it:
populate_with_examples_recursive(ExampleData)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 'abc-123-45', 'c': 100, 'n': {'a': 'hello'}}
```